# Canceling a http request based on the status of other requests in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, http

I have two types of http get requests:
1. /abcdocsearch and
2. /reloadList

The /reloadList response is much slower than /abcdocsearch. I want to cancel the /abcdocsearch request if the /reloadList request called after it is already fulfilled.

How can I do this in Javascript.
I am using some private libraries to make these calls.

## EDIT

the library internally uses goog.Promise - https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.Promise.html and I can get this promise object.

I tried using 
`goog.Promise.cancel("error")`, however, the request did not get canceled and is still fulfilled.

Comment: *"I am using some private libraries to make these calls."* It's difficult to help you if we don't know what API to interact with. Please provide some example code.

Comment: Like @gyre said it depends on what method you are using to make the request. For example, a fetch request cannot be cancelled. On the other hand on a XMLHttpRequest request you can use abort().

Comment: @gyre modified the content.

Answer (score 0):

According to the included API doc, there is no static function called `cancel` on `goog.Promise`,  there is however an instance function on promises' objects, so to cancel a promise, you need to cancel on a promise instance like this

```
var promise = goog.Promise(/* pass your callbacks here*/);
.
.
.
promise.cancel(/*reason*/);
```

I highly doubt that if you open the console, you will see an error message like `cancel is not defined on goog.Promise`